# Why do I have to Enumerate before call FirstOrDefault?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have no idea of why the code below throws without the ToSomeEnumerable() before the firstOrDefault, I did not found anything anywhere that would explain why use strait way firstOrDefault would not work. Can someone explain what is the problem?

```
public DateTime? GetOldestUpdDate(int field1Id, DateTime threshold)
{
    var query = @"SELECT MIN(updated_at) AS updated_at FROM my_table WHERE field_1_id = @field_1_id AND updated_at < @threshold;";
  
        return _context.Database.SqlQueryRaw<DateTime?>(
            query,
            new MySqlParameter("field_1_id", field1Id),
            new MySqlParameter("threshold", threshold.DateString()))
            //.ToList() without this, it throws saying that there is an error in the sql query
            .FirstOrDefault();
    
}
```

That is the exception

> {*stackTrace: {sbyte[1536]}  Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ';
> ) AS `t`
> LIMIT 2' at line 3  StackTrace:    at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 43
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 468 at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, Activity activity, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/Core/CommandExecutor.cs:line 56
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 344
> at MySqlConnector.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in /*/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlCommand.cs:line 278
> at
> Etc..

Comment: *there is an error in the sql query* What error ?

Comment: Since that query should only ever return a single value, why are you using a method that implies some form or ordering and yet not applying any ordering criteria?

Comment: You state that it throws an SQL error. Your query is most likely wrong and thus returns null. You cant operate `.FirstOrDefault()` on null. You can on an empty enumeration.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did not understand what you said/ask

Comment: @Roe the query is fine, it works when I use some ToList (as I wrote in the code example)

Comment: `IQueryable.FirstOrDefault` prolly adding `) as t LIMIT 2` when query is builded ... removing `;` should fix the problem while (`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(...)` doesn't)

Comment: @Selvin I thought about it, I have a different exception message if I do so:

Message: Unknown column 't.Value' in 'field list'  StackTrace:    at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/ResultSet.cs:line 43
   at

Comment: Well, then change `AS updated_at` to `AS Value` ... using  `SqlQueryRaw` when working with EF is not  great idea ... espetially if you can just use `context.my_table.Where(...).Max(x=>x.updated_at)`

Comment: @Selvin Indeed that makes it work, but what is the problem with AS updated_at?
I'm not allowed to use an alias if there is a column with the same name?

Comment: lets assume your query is `SELECT something` ... now (I don't know why) `FirstOrDefault` makes it looks like `SELECT t.Value FROM (SELECT something) as t LIMIT 2` ... and you have the problem

Comment: I would suggest getting a trial of Entity Framework Profiler so you can see the SQL that gets generated for each attempt.  https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof

Comment: I guess the elephant in the room is "why are you using EF to execute a statement like that?" EF will be expecting results from `SqlQueryRaw` to be treated like an `IQueryable<T>`  If you just want to return a scalar value from an operation then use `ExecuteSqlCommand` and provide it the output parameter, or just write the query against the DbSet and use `FirstOrDefault` with an `OrderBy` instead of `MIN()`.

Comment: @StevePy Can you give me an example? I did not find the method ExecuteSqlCommand

Comment: @Selvin _"now (I don't know why) `FirstOrDefault` ..  `LIMIT 2`"_maybe it is sharing code with `Single`? =)

Answer (score -1):

The `SqlQueryRaw` method returns an `IEnumerable` of the type specified as its generic argument. In this case, it returns an `IEnumerable<DateTime?>`.

When you call `FirstOrDefault` directly on the result of `SqlQueryRaw`, it is essentially trying to return the first item in the IEnumerable. However, because the `IEnumerable` has not yet been enumerated (i.e. the SQL query has not been executed yet), the `FirstOrDefault` method is unable to retrieve any items and throws an exception.

Calling `ToList` before `FirstOrDefault` forces the enumeration of the `IEnumerable` and returns a `List<DateTime?>` object. The `FirstOrDefault` method can then safely retrieve the first item in the list, which in this case is the single `DateTime?` value returned by the SQL query.

Therefore, the `ToList` method is necessary in this case to ensure that the SQL query is executed and the `SqlQueryRaw` method returns a list of `DateTime?` values that can be used with `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: 1) _"The `SqlQueryRaw` method returns an `IEnumerable`"_ - it returns not just `IEnumerable` but [`IQueryable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.sqlqueryraw?view=efcore-7.0). 2) _"(i.e. the SQL query has not been executed yet), the FirstOrDefault method is unable to retrieve any items and throws an exception."_ - if this was the reason `ToList` would not work too. The problem is the faulty SQL generation caused by using `select min`  and materialization via `FirstOrDefault`.